# How to determine if hardware virtualization is available via code? (C#, C++)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, virtualization

How can I detect if a system supports hardware virtualization via code?
(Preferably in C# or C++).

I tried using WMI and ManagementObjectSearcher, and could not find a property that seemed to represent if virtualization support was present or not in the machine.

Bonus question:
Is it possible to tell if the CPU supports HW virtualization, but disabled in BIOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the original poster is asking how to detect that the computer hardware supports virtualisation, not that it is running inside a virtual machine. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658/determine-if-my-pc-supports-hw-virtualization) for a possible answer.

Also, it might be worth seeing if you can check the CPU flags, as there will either be the Intel `vmx` flag or the AMD `svm` flag if the processor supports virtualisation extensions. I can't say I know how this should be done under Windows, but the information is available in `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

I do not have a C-ish answer, but here's a PowerShell approach -- it's just a simple WMI query -- that can help.

Query Win32_Processor; there are flags "SecondLevelAddressTranslationExtensions" and "VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled."  They seem to answer the questions for me.

In PoSH, it's

(GWMI Win32_Processor).VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled

and

(GWMI Win32_Processor).SecondLevelAddressTranslationExtensions

I hope this helps.

Mark Minasi

Comment: Both commands return False for me, but I have Hyper-V virtualization enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the code, but [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) seems to be able to do this.

Comment: Exactly like this application - but I need to do it in code. I have searched WMI query results high and low and could not find any property that seemed to be connected to HW virtualization

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841536/is-it-possible-using-c-sharp-to-check-if-hardware-virtualization-enabled/24842577#24842577), as you can see there, maybe you should use WMI classes to get info. .NET framework has System.Management namespace to do that. Win32_processor class can give you all info you need about processor, because you can't access the cpu flags directly using win32_processor class, maybe you need to check the value of VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled

Answer (score -2):

check [StackOverFlow: How to identify that you’re running under a VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533/how-to-identify-that-youre-running-under-a-vm)