# Running VirtualBox in Ubuntu in Mac OSX, won't start up

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, docker

I am getting started with Docker, and I am trying to run a Vagrant VirtualBox in Ubuntu running inside another VirtualBox in Mac OSX (10.9, latest versions of everything).

I cannot start the inner virtual box, giving me a message VT-x not available. VT-x is enabled in the out VirtualBox, not sure what is missing!

Comment: What Vagrant box are you trying to use on the inner VirtualBox?

Comment: AFAIK it is possible that hardware virtualisation is disabled within the VM. Question is: Can you start any VM (even without vagrant) inside the other VM? You may check kernel support with command **egrep '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo**. More reading about hardware virtualization here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658/determine-if-my-pc-supports-hw-virtualization

Answer (score 2):

VT-x inside VT-x cannot be done in VirtualBox.

A (quite old) feature request about this functionality is here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032